# XML output is incorrect

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net

I have a form written in VB.NET with ASP.NET that writes the users data to an XML file. Each time the form is used, a new XML file is generated with the data provided via the form. My problem is I'm trying to get the XML output to resemble:

```
<PersonalData>
  <products>
    <product>
      <productID>1</productID>
      <productNumber>123456</productNumber>
    </product>
 </products>
  <customers>
     <customer>
        <LastName>Winchester</LastName>
        <FirstName>Sam</FirstName>
        <Address>1234 Elm RD</Address>
        <City>San Antonio</City>
        <State>Texas</State>
        <ZipCode>76345</ZipCode>
      </customer>
   </customers>
</PersonalData>
```

however, I end up with:

```
<PersonalData>
  <products>
    <product>
      <productID>1</productID>
      <productNumber>123456</productNumber>
      <customers>
        <customer>
          <LastName>Winchester</LastName>
          <FirstName>Sam</FirstName>
          <Address>1234 Elm RD</Address>
          <City>San Antonio</City>
          <State>Texas</State>
          <ZipCode>76345</ZipCode>
        </customer>
      </customers>
    </product>
  </products>
</PersonalData>
```

This is my code -button click-:

```vb
 Public Sub Write_XML(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim textWriter As New XmlTextWriter(Server.MapPath("xml/PersonDataVI.xml"), Nothing)
        textWriter.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented
        'Start New Document
        textWriter.WriteStartDocument()
        'Write a Comment
        textWriter.WriteComment("This is a comment")
        'Insert Start Element -root element node
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("PersonalData")
        'write the start element
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("products")
        'write the child start element
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("product")
        'Write ProductID Element and Data
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("productID", "")
        textWriter.WriteString(txtProductID.Text)
        textWriter.WriteEndElement()
        'Write ProductID Element and Data
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("productNumber", "")
        textWriter.WriteString(txtProductNum.Text)
        textWriter.WriteEndElement()
        'write the child element
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("customers")
        'write the child element
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("customer")
        'Write LastName Element and Data
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("LastName", "")
        textWriter.WriteString(txtLastName.Text)
        textWriter.WriteEndElement()
        'Write FirstName Element and Data
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("FirstName", "")
        textWriter.WriteString(txtFirstName.Text)
        textWriter.WriteEndElement()
        'Write Address Element and Data
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("Address", "")
        textWriter.WriteString(txtAddress.Text)
        textWriter.WriteEndElement()
        'Write City Element and Data
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("City", "")
        textWriter.WriteString(txtCity.Text)
        textWriter.WriteEndElement()
        'Write State Element and Data
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("State", "")
        textWriter.WriteString(txtState.Text)
        textWriter.WriteEndElement()
        'Write ZipCode Elment and Data
        textWriter.WriteStartElement("ZipCode", "")
        textWriter.WriteString(txtZipCode.Text)
        textWriter.WriteEndElement()
        'End Everything
        textWriter.WriteEndDocument()
        'Clean up
        textWriter.Flush()
        textWriter.Close()
        'Display the XML Document
        Response.Redirect(Server.MapPath("xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))
    End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a `WriteEndElement` for `product` and `products`.

After

```vb
textWriter.WriteStartElement("productNumber", "")
textWriter.WriteString(txtProductNum.Text)
textWriter.WriteEndElement()
```

You need two more

```vb
textWriter.WriteEndElement()
```

Comment: Think of it like HTML.  Every opening tag needs a closing tag.  WriteEndElement is the closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

After you do the end element for product number you will need to do another two calls to end element.

```vb
Public Sub Write_XML(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Dim textWriter As New XmlTextWriter(Server.MapPath("xml/PersonDataVI.xml"), Nothing)
    textWriter.Formatting = System.Xml.Formatting.Indented
    'Start New Document
    textWriter.WriteStartDocument()
    'Write a Comment
    textWriter.WriteComment("This is a comment")
    'Insert Start Element -root element node
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("PersonalData")
    'write the start element
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("products")
    'write the child start element
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("product")
    'Write ProductID Element and Data
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("productID", "")
    textWriter.WriteString(txtProductID.Text)
    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    'Write ProductID Element and Data
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("productNumber", "")
    textWriter.WriteString(txtProductNum.Text)
    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    'write the child element
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("customers")
    'write the child element
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("customer")
    'Write LastName Element and Data
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("LastName", "")
    textWriter.WriteString(txtLastName.Text)
    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    'Write FirstName Element and Data
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("FirstName", "")
    textWriter.WriteString(txtFirstName.Text)
    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    'Write Address Element and Data
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("Address", "")
    textWriter.WriteString(txtAddress.Text)
    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    'Write City Element and Data
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("City", "")
    textWriter.WriteString(txtCity.Text)
    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    'Write State Element and Data
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("State", "")
    textWriter.WriteString(txtState.Text)
    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    'Write ZipCode Elment and Data
    textWriter.WriteStartElement("ZipCode", "")
    textWriter.WriteString(txtZipCode.Text)
    textWriter.WriteEndElement()
    'End Everything
    textWriter.WriteEndDocument()
    'Clean up
    textWriter.Flush()
    textWriter.Close()
    'Display the XML Document
    Response.Redirect(Server.MapPath("xml/PersonDataVI.xml"))
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VB 9 or greater, consider using LINQ to XML rather than the explicit writer. With that you can do simply:

```
Dim myData = <PersonalData>
  <products>
    <product>
      <productID>1</productID>
      <productNumber>123456</productNumber>
    </product>
 </products>
  <customers>
     <customer>
        <LastName>Winchester</LastName>
        <FirstName>Sam</FirstName>
        <Address>1234 Elm RD</Address>
        <City>San Antonio</City>
        <State>Texas</State>
        <ZipCode>76345</ZipCode>
      </customer>
   </customers>
</PersonalData>
```

To insert values, just escape them like you would in ASP.Net:

```
<productID><% myProduct.ID %></productID>
```